# What to put in the Type targetType parameter in IValueConverter

Tags: c#, types, windows-phone-8, ivalueconverter

I am calling a IValueConverter class via code behind, but I am not sure what to put in the `Type targetType` parameter. The object is `string` but using that give me 'invalid expression term 'string'`

my code to call the converter

```
secondConverter.Convert(score, string, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The converter class

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)value);

        return String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                        ts.Hours,
                        ts.Minutes,
                        ts.Seconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `typeof(string)` instead of string, but your converter does not seem to use or validate target type, so you can put just about anything there, including null.

Generally, your converter should at least validate that target type is string and throw exception if it is not.

Comment: using `typeof(string)` gives me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: @PutraKg Your method returns an object. What do you do with that value?

Comment: Ah I fixed that using an object variable for the return object then cast it to string

Comment: @PutraKg So, all solved? Then you should probably mark alex's answer here as the answer. It has a better explanation than mine. =)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want

```
secondConverter.Convert(score, typeof(string), null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

to actually make it a parameter of type `Type`.